# OAuth2 and C# Web Forms

Tags: ms-office, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get some Calendar Information from Office 365 into a web app. Are there any examples on how to do this using c# web forms? I came across some examples but they were written in MVC. I am not 100% familiar with that language structure yet.

Answer (score 0):

The following blog samples are using an ASP.Net web application as a base sample for exploring the Office 365 Exchange REST interface.
Hopefully might point you in the right direction.
(Just starting on this journey myself at the moment!)
Email and Calendaring links as a walk-through
http://mobilitydojo.net/2014/03/24/microsoft-provides-a-restful-api-for-exchange-part-1/
http://mobilitydojo.net/2014/03/25/microsoft-provides-a-restful-api-for-exchange-part-2/

(Edit: Apologies this does use the MVC structure inside a Web app.
However there are "basic MVC tutorials" via Bing on YouTube (18mins), W3schools and ASP.Net so you can understand the 3 pieces).

Regards
Ruth